# How to sequentially append data frames in to a list without making sub and sub-sub lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

When I add data frames sequentially in to a list object, I make not a single list, but list of list and so on. For example,

```
d1 = data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3))
d2 = data.frame(V1 = c(1,3,4))
mainList = list(d1, d2)
```

when I want to append an another data.frame in to mainList,

```
d3 = data.frame(V3 = c(1,3,4))
mainList = list(mainList,d3)
```

The main list becomes like this.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  V1
1  1
2  2
3  3

[[1]][[2]]
  V1
1  1
2  3
3  4


[[2]]
  V3
1  1
2  3
3  4
```

How to do this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after ... you want length(mainList) == 3? Does mainList = c(mainList,d3) do what you want?

Comment: I think you want `c(mainList, list(d3))`

Comment: Wow that's weird. I don't think I'll ever understand nested lists

Comment: @Richard Yeah! I want that exactly. `c(mainList, list(d3))` Thanks !

Comment: I think @Richard's approach might involve making a copy. You could instead do `mainList[[length(mainList)+1]] <- d3`

Comment: @Frank: I think that `<-` will always be making a copy as well.

Comment: @BondedDust Oh, you're right. I guess the only way to avoid it would be to have preallocated `mainList` to the correct length (but it may be too late for that in the OP's case), like `mainList <- vector("list",3); mainList[] <- list(d1, d2, d3)`. A call to `address` before and after the second command confirms (?) that that avoids a copy.

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff can you post this as the answer?